# Saving a hasMany relationship containing array of IDs back to REST server using Ember-Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am using Ember-Data 1.0 Beta 2.

I have a model that contains an attribute containing a list of IDs as an array. It's defined as a hasMany relationship, see below:

```
Lrt.User = DS.Model.extend({ 
jobRole: hasMany('jobRole', {async:true, embedded:'always'}),
});
```

When I do a model.save(), the POST payload shows that "jobRole" is empty, as in [].

How do I save the hasMany relationship back using Ember-Data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a hasMany, then you want to be setting `'jobRole'` with a collection of live `JobRole` objects, not with an array of IDs.

```
// assume role1 and role2 are JobRole objects
// obtained via store.find()  (or something...)
someUser.set('jobRole',[role1,role2]);
```

Alternatively, if you want to set the property with a list of IDs, then you could just use a non-typed `DS.attr` and the array will be passed through as is.

```
Lrt.User = DS.Model.extend({ 
  jobRole: DS.attr()
});

//then later
someUser.set('jobRole',[1,42]);
```

Comment: Well I'm confused because in the docs, it states that it's expecting a list of IDs and not objects. It's working right now that if I return a list of IDs from the server, the hasMany relationship loads the related models from the server and then they are available elsewhere in the app as individual model objects. This way, won't they only be usable in this model? If I can receive a list of IDs, I don't know why it won't send them back.

Comment: It's just a matter of context.  Inside the Ember app itself it always wants to deal with relationships between real objects.  That's why you can call `user.get('jobRole')` and get back a live collection of `JobRole` objects, even though what you delivered from the server is an array of `JobRole` ids.  Conversely when you go to save a relationship, Ember still wants to deal with live objects internally, but it wants to send only the IDs of those objects back to the server.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I'm still a slight bit confused. The REST adapter makes a request for the model from the server. The JSON payload for 'jobRole' comes back with an array of IDs, which ember data connects to actual model objects. Am I supposed to return the full pojo of each jobRole object in the JSON payload from the REST server? Everything else is working up to the point of saving the list of IDs back to the server.

Comment: By using `async : true` you're telling Ember that you expect to deliver those objects separately from the main model.  You could use `async : false` (or just omit the async param), but then you would need to "side load" that data.  The "comments" array here is an example of side loading : http://emberjs.com/guides/models/connecting-to-an-http-server/#toc_json-conventions

Comment: Brilliant! Ok. Sideloading is the way to go in my case. Thanks!